# Construction of a smooth function $\varphi$ such that the sum of $\varphi(2^{-n}t)$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis

I want to construct $\varphi \in C_c(\mathbb R)$ whose support is in $[\frac 1 2 ,2]$, satisfying $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \varphi(2^{-n}t)=1$ for all $t>0$. I guess I should use Urysohn's lemma, but how to?

Comment: $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ means merely _continuous_ and compactly supported. Since you have "smooth" in the title, you probably meant $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: You are right! Thx

Answer (score 2):

1. Take any smooth function $\psi$ supported on $[1/2,2]$ and strictly positive on $[3/4,3/2]$.
2. The function $\Psi(t) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \psi(2^{-n}t)$ is smooth and positive for all $t>0$. Also, $\Psi(2t)=\Psi(t)$.
3. Let $\varphi(t) = \psi(t)/\Psi(t)$; this function satisfies the requirements because 
   $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \varphi(2^{-n}t)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \psi(2^{-n}t) / \Psi(t) = 1$$

Comment: Thx a lot! Can I choose an interval where $\psi$ is strictly positive arbitrarily?

Comment: Any interval $[a,b]$ with $b\ge 2a$ will do. The point is that for any $t>0$, the product $2^{-n}t$ will fall into this interval for some $n$.